# force two digits on an array for a 15 puzzle game

Tags: c#, arrays, console, grid

I am making a 15 puzzle game for school but right now it only has 9 numbers but if i add 2 digit numbers it messes up the whole grid. So I want there to be 2 digits on all numbers (2→→02).

`int[,] tab  = { { 2, 1, 7 }, {  6, 9, 4 }, {  3, 0, 7 } };`

Comment: Could you do strings for the table and cast to an int when you need it? Or if you are printing to console you could use String.fomat to add leading zeros

Comment: Assuming you're printing the int array directly, you'd be looking for the [zero-placeholder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the-0-custom-specifier) format specifier. Using `:00` ensures all numbers are at least two digits, with single digit numbers having a 0 prepended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are working with an 2D array you can do something like this:

```
int[,] tab  = { { 2, 1, 7 }, {  6, 9, 4 }, {  3, 0, 7 } };

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      Console.Write(String.Format("{0,2:00} ", tab[i,j]));
   }
   Console.Write("\n");
}
```

Here we are using String.Format to print the numbers as two digits. Since there is only one digit for the integers in the table, a leading zero will automatically be added. So for your code the output would be:

```
02 01 07
06 09 04
03 00 07
```

Answer (score 0):

When displaying the numbers, format the strings. Here's an example:

```
int value = 2;
string result = String.Format("{0,2:00}", value);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The example displays the following output:
`02`